# Internationalization in the if statement

Tags: angular, if-statement, internationalization

I wonder if is a dispute if i18n works in the case below

```
<ng-container *ngIf="anything" i18n>Something to translate</ng-container>
```

According to one person, i18n won't work and it should look like this:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="anything"><span i18n>Something to translate</span></ng-container>
```

My question is is there anythng wrong with the first way? If yes, then why it would not work?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why this would not work. Check the following example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/i18n-examples-szzdhi?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

1. The ng-container can be used with i18n in order to avoid adding an html element like span (look into the [angular docs here](https://angular.io/guide/i18n) for the following example)

   `<ng-container i18n>I don't output any element</ng-container>`
2. The ng container works perfectly fine with the ngIf directive([angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives))

   `<p>
     I turned the corner
     <ng-container *ngIf="hero">
       and saw {{hero.name}}. I waved
     </ng-container>
     and continued on my way.
   </p>`